# httpWebRequest Json POST to Mojang Server is returning 403

Tags: c#, json, ssl, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to make a json POST to the Mojang authentification server using a `HttpWebRequest` in C#.
I checked the headers with a Chrome addon and added them. 
Below is my code, but I keep getting a `403 forbidden`. 
I got it working with a `TcpClient` but I need to do it with a `HttpWebRequest` as it accepts proxies.
Does someone now how to fix this?

```
  public void test(string username, string password) {

    try {

   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
   ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

   string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"clientToken\":\"6c9d237d-8fbf-44ef-b46b-0b8a854bf391\"}";

   var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");

   httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
   httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
   httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
   httpWebRequest.Host = "authserver.mojang.com";
   httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
   httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
   httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
   httpWebRequest.Referer = "https://authserver.mojang.com/";
   httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
   httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");


  using(var streamWriter = new  StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
  }


   var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   MessageBox.Show(result);
   streamReader.Close();
  }


  } catch (Exception error) {
  MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Best method is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the TCP results with the httpWebRequest results.  Make sure that you run test with cookies removed.  You can delete cookies by using a IE and delete history.  Make sure the version of http is 1.0 (not 1.1).  Version 1.1 doesn't work with the Net Library it is chunk mode and I have not found a method in Net to request the 2nd chunk.

Comment: Added httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; still same

Comment: Did you clear cookies afterwards?  What differences are you seeing in sniffer?

Comment: how to get wireshark to decrypt ssl?

Comment: I thought is automatically decrypt message.  Look at body.  Do you see decrypt data when it works with TCP?

Comment: Yes its decrypted

Comment: So you have to find out what the differences are between the TCP and the httpRequest.  Obviously there is a difference since the TCP de-crypts and http doesn't.